# FaceBook Page Photo upload - (#324) Requires upload file

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the FB JS SDK to (attempt) to upload a photo to a users page.

However I keep getting the "**324 Requires upload file**" error, in the code I have tried everything from a url of the photo to a blob file upload and have had no success.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I cant seem to bang this one out.
Here is the photo posting function I have written as of yet.

So far, the function can get my list of pages, it then matches with the page I want to post to.  Once that's complete I attempt to push the image to FB using the **FB.api('/page-ID/photos')** api call, but that's where it fails on me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function uploadPhoto() {
// Get the access token for the user.
  FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      // Get the access token for the user's page.
      var pageAccessToken = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        console.log('Looking....' + response.data.length);
        console.log(response.data[i]);
        if (response.data[i].id === '101674985359608') {
          pageAccessToken = response.data[i].access_token;
          console.log('Found: ' + response.data[i].id);
          break;
        }
      }

      // Load the photo file url into the function
      var photoPath = 'https://patriciapick.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/20220803_180813-scaled.jpg';
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('url', photoPath);
      formData.append('access_token', pageAccessToken);
      FB.api('/101674985359608/photos', 'POST', formData, function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log('Photo uploaded successfully.');
        } else {
          console.log('Error uploading photo: ' + response.error.message);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
      
    } else {
      console.log('Error getting page access token: ' + response.error.message);
    }
  });
}
```

EDIT: Modified the code to show that I'm only attempting to post a URL to the FB JS SDK, but I'm still getting the same 324 error.

Comment: Checking the `source` entry in that FormData object, your code gives me an element with `size: 78`, which can't be right for that image you got there. (Can't tell whether this is due to any CORS restrictions though, but I did not see any error relating to CORS.)

Comment: CORS hasn't ben the issue, It appears that the systems are working correctly since I can get a list of pages and identify one to send too.  My problems (I think) is isolated to the files itself.  as well, I cant seem to find the 'source' attribute in the documentation but even 'url' gives me the same error, I have just left the code where it is at for this question.   As I said in the question, i have tried to give the FB SDK a url as well and it gives me the same answer.

Comment: I am not talking about your other API requests, but whether your filereader can read `photoPath` in the first place. That URL does not appear to be CORS-enabled, so I think if your code was not running under the origin `https://patriciapick.com/`, I don't think this should be expected to work.

Comment: _"I cant seem to find the 'source' attribute in the documentation"_ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#upload _"but even 'url' gives me the same error"_ - in that case, you removed all the filereader stuff then, and supplied the URL as plain text - yes?

Comment: 'in that case, you removed all the filereader stuff then, and supplied the URL as plain text - yes?'   Yes, that is correct and I get the same results.  As well I am retrieving the file from the same domain.

Comment: @CBroe am I making the URL request incorrectly ?

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong with it from looking at the code.